# NullPointerException from getExtras()

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle

I'm creating an intent to transfer data from one activity to another like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHighScore.class);
    intent.putExtra("USERNAME", username);
    intent.putExtra("PLAYERMOVES", playerMoves);

    this.startActivity(intent);
```

Then i want to check if all of this data exists as the activity starts, as it can be started from other sources without this data being set. Im using this statement:

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (!bundle.getString("USERNAME").equals(null) && bundle.getInt("PLAYERMOVES") != 0){
        String username = bundle.getString("USERNAME");
        int playerMoves = bundle.getInt("PLAYERMOVES");
        addHighScore(username, playerMoves);

    }
```

But this causes a null pointerexception and I'm entirely sure how. I thought I was getting to grips with Strings and .equals(), but I think its that... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (!bundle.getString("USERNAME").equals(null) && bundle.getInt("PLAYERMOVES") != 0){
        String username = bundle.getString("USERNAME");
        int playerMoves = bundle.getInt("PLAYERMOVES");
        addHighScore(username, playerMoves);

    }
```

with

```
 if (getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME") != null && (getIntent().getIntExtra("PLAYERMOVES", 0) != 0){
        String username = bundle.getString("USERNAME");
        int playerMoves = bundle.getInt("PLAYERMOVES");
        addHighScore(username, playerMoves);

  }
```

Comment: This still returns a null pointer exception sadly, logCat says it is from the same line :(

Comment: The solution worked for me.But why isn't it working with the above solution?

Comment: @Muhammad Umair Shafique If the string is null it has no methods. How could it have equals()?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had a similar problem. In my case the `NullPointerException` happened when I checked if my `bundle.getString()` was equal to `null`.

Here is how I solved it, in my case:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();        
if(intent.hasExtra("nomeUsuario")){
    bd = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(!bd.getString("nomeUsuario").equals(null)){
        nomeUsuario = bd.getString("nomeUsuario");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method which you are doing is correct . The null pointer exception is coming because the fragment is not replaced with the right fragment object.
 **Here is the working code Activity class**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "helloo");
Home tm = new Home();
tm.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag,tm).commit();
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
item.setChecked(true);
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

**the code for receiving in fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    String myValue = getArguments().getString("message");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return myview;
}
```

Do let me know if it helps!